# Hide LinearLayout once during the open keyboard button is pressed Back

Tags: android

I do not know how can I arrange this. Many methods have been tried.
I need to after, locked keyboard hiding LinerLayout, this code does not work.

How do I arrange this?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visible="visible">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/mark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/Content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/greeting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/greeting_default"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/text_on_white"
                android:background="@color/mark"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/greeting_ok"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/mark"
                android:textColor="@color/text_on_white"
                android:text="@string/greeting_ok"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Context `CustomLinearLayout.class`

```
package my.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    Context context;

    public CustomLinerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            LinearLayout menu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);
            menu.setVisibility(GONE);

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`Profile.class`

```
package my.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomLinearLayout menu;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_application);


        menu = (CustomLinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);

        menu.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);



    }




    }
```

Comment: Light corrections and formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `CustomLinearLayout` is not in focus, therefore it doesn't receive any keyboard events. What you can do is make it focusable either in xml or code like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_application);
    menu = (CustomLinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    menu.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);

    menu.setFocusable(true);
    menu.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

Also in your layout class, you need to return `true` if event was handled to prevent system to handle it:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        LinearLayout menu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        menu.setVisibility(GONE);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But this won't help you if there is, for example, `EditText` which you give focus to after `onCreate`